# Memory error when running unit tests in SonarQube -- forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye

Tags: java, maven, out-of-memory, sonarqube, maven-surefire-plugin

We are consistently getting out of memory errors when running our sonar analysis. It is intermittent across machines, but seems once you get it, it persists.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test   (default-cli) on project optimus-client-web-configuration: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:    

maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
[ERROR] Command wascmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\java" -javaagent:C:\Users\cxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\jacocoagent8301608889470684052.jar=destfile=target/jacoco.exec,excludes=
*_javassist_* -jar C:\redesign_Trunk\optimus-lms-server\optimus-client-web-configuration\target\surefire\surefirebooter2312966376869893038.jar C:\redesign_Trunk\optimus-lms-server\optimus-client-web-con
figuration\target\surefire\surefire350975689095180011tmp C:\redesign_Trunk\xxx-xx-server\xxx\target\surefire\surefire_45613339175612175619tmp"
```

The unit tests do not fail with this when running before the sonar phase. It is occurring on one particular test that activates the Spring configuration to test that it works okay. Likely this test consumes more memory than most since it has to load the whole context.

I upped memory in MAVEN_OPTS to use 1024M max heap. Added this configuration to my pom

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

in this configuration you are just configuring surefire plugin to use this memory when it spawns new jvm, you need to increase memory for `mvn`'s jvm as well

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2048m"
```

try above (with proper memory size)

Comment: To do so directly in Maven command, add this to the argLine parameter, as follow: **mvn -DargLine="-Xmx2048m"** {... rest of maven arguments}

Answer (score 0):

Another solutions: **Run application [Eclipse IDE, SonarQube...] as administrator**

Problem:
1. When error log contains: '... VM terminated without saying properly goodbye ...'
2. Error log contains: "cmd.exe /C ... error something ..."
3. Error log contains: '... **java.io.tmpdir** ... **c:\windows**'